# JS: How I can detect if HTML was successfully copied to the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

**This sample code for copying plain text seems to work with most browsers…**

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(() => {
    console.log("Copied.");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error.");
});
```

**…whereas this sample code for copying HTML to the clipboard does NOT work with Mobile Chrome nor does it return an error…**

```
navigator.permissions.query({name: "clipboard-write"}).then((result) => {
    if (result.state === "granted" || result.state === "prompt") {
        const blobInput = new Blob([exportContent], {type: "text/html"});
        const clipboardItemInput = new ClipboardItem({"text/html" : blobInput});                        

        navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardItemInput]).then(() => {
            console.log("Copied");
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Error.");
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("Permission denied.");
    }   
});
```

Is there another way to construct the second example to work in Android; and if not, how can I detect the failure given that `navigator.clipboard.write` does not return an error in Mobile Chrome?

---

**UPDATE:  Better-Than-Nothing Workaround**

Given that I'm not hopeful that this can be resolved without Google addressing the issue, I at least wanted to: (1) find a way to not have users blame my website/app for the Clipboard being empty; (2) not get on the slippery slope of trying to detect the devices that have the problem along with writing special case code; and (3) ensure that the process immediately starts working if Google ever gets around to fixing the problem. So…

Since I can successfully write plain text to the keyboard, I now have two parts to the code:

1. I first write a plain text message like "[App name] sent HTML to the Clipboard. If this is what got pasted, it means your device is…[along with a suggested alternative of attaching the content in a file in lieu of pasting]."
2. I then attempt to write the HTML to the Clipboard.

When writing the HTML works, the user doesn't see the message from Part 1 when pasting. When it doesn't work, the user sees the message and at least knows more about the problem and an alternative.

---

**FINAL UPDATE**

I have come to believe the HTML is on the Clipboard but not consistently accessible. That explains the reason for no errors being thrown. If I can get Gmail in Android to display a context menu, which it only does 20% of the time, I can successfully paste the HTML. GBoard never shows the HTML content but always shows the plain text.

I can live with the aforementioned workaround. It's a minor hassle for users the first time they encounter the issue, but after they realize their device has a problem, they just start using the alternative (which actually has some benefits).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: @Camilo: Thank you. That's definitely relevant to how the process is supposed to work. Unless there's something I'm not understanding about the code, the problem is that Android doesn't report an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue and I tried hard to solve it till I found that some mobile browsers just don't support it. So your first simple code is the best solution but instead of showing an error, I suggest you show a prompt telling the user to copy the given text in case the browser can't do it or doesn't support it.

```
function copyText() {

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(() => {
      alert("text is copied to clipboard");
    }, () => {
      window.prompt("Please copy this text", text);
    });
  }
```

Edit: regarding your comment, for that you can just put the prompt block in try and catch:

```
function copyText() {

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(() => {
      alert("text is copied to clipboard");
    }, () => {

      try {

        window.prompt("Please copy this text", text);

      } catch (error) {
        
        alert("Your browser doesn't support this function");
      }
      
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I tried the prompting approach initially, but because the process works on more than half of the devices, it was too distracting for those users. And since there's no error returned, and I don't want to start trying to identify devices, nor track which ones work and which ones don't, I wanted to find a way to notify only those who are adversely affected.

Comment: @AlanM. for that you can use `try and catch` I updated my answer. please check.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but nothing throws an error.